# Why do I get this error about empty list?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have made these functions:

```
-- Looks up in dict and returns Maybe key
myLookUp :: [(String, [String])] -> String -> String
myLookUp [] val = []
myLookUp ((k, vs):ds) val
  | val `elem` snd (myLast ds) = myCensor val
  | val `elem` vs = k
  | otherwise = myLookUp ds val

-- Given a dict of tuples of strings and list of strings, 
-- should return the last tuple in dict
myLast :: [(String, [String])] -> (String, [String])
myLast [] = error "Empty list"
myLast [x] = x
myLast (x:xs) = myLast xs
```

Which compiles, but when I try to test it I get an error saying

```
ghci> myLookUp [("strength", ["ignorance"]), ("bla", ["blabla", "blabla"])] "aa"

*** Exception: Empty list
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at test.hs:103:13 in main:Main
```

And if I try to remove my base case `myLast [] = error "Empty list"` I get this error:

```
 myLookUp [("strength", ["ignorance"]), ("bla", ["blabla", "blabla"])] "aa"

    *** Exception: test.hs:(104,1)-(105,25): 
    Non-exhaustive patterns in function myLast
```

I think that `myLast` works because I get this output:

```
myLast [("strength", ["ignorance"]), ("bla", ["blabla", "blabla"])]
("bla",["blabla","blabla"])
```

And I thought I could use `snd` on the tuple to get the list-element, but since I get this error, I'm uncertain as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: In ``val `elem` snd (myLast ds)`` there is no guarantee that `ds` is nonempty. Indeed, as soon as `myLookup` is called with a list of length one, that will happen.

Comment: The value of `myLast ds` isn't going to change between recursive calls; you could compute that once when `myLookup` is first called, then use a helper function that does the actual recursion without repeatedly recomputing git.

Comment: Something like `loc sub str = if val elem snd (myLast ds) then myCensor val else myLookUp` ?

Comment: because you wrote `myLast [] = error "Empty list"`. and if you'd written `myLast [] = error "Empty list 123"`, you'd get the error `"Empty list 123"` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to think a little closer about what you are trying to do. The reason you get an empty list exception here is because you try to pass myLast a list that may be empty (and will be empty by the last iteration). You have no check in your guards for when there is a single element left in the input list (ds). You can do this by adding:

```
| null ds = []
```

Or check for a single element in the function pattern. Furthermore the myLast function is identical to the built in prelude function "last", so it could replace that.
Also keep in mind where you place your null check for ds, it has to be before you attempt to use ds, but after your first check:

```
myLookUp :: [(String, [String])] -> String -> String
myLookUp [] val = []
myLookUp ((k, vs):ds) val
  | val `elem` vs = k
  | null ds = []
  | val `elem` snd (last ds) = myCensor val
  | otherwise = myLookUp ds val
```

A better approach to this problem is to only check against the elements that are in the head per iteration, it is wildly inefficient to check the last element on every single iteration, when you only have to do it once, and it will be done on the last iteration of the recursive loop anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what it seems like you're trying to do:

> Given a dictionary mapping keys (strings) to values (lists of strings), and a string-value to look up, first determine if the given value is present in the list contained in the last entry of the dictionary. If so, then censor the value and return it. Otherwise, determine if the given value is present in some value-list; if so, return the associated key. If not, return Nothing.

Wouldn't it make more sense to have the "list of strings that need censorship" be a separate argument? Then a solution would be:

```
import Data.List (find)

myLookup :: [String] -> [(String, [String])] -> String -> Maybe String
myLookup toCensor dict val
  | val `elem` toCensor = Just $ myCensor val
  | Just (key, _) <- find (\(_, vs) -> val `elem` vs) dict = Just key
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

Comment: I have a text and a dict of tuples where the last tuple has the words I want to censor, while the others are just key-words I want to exchange. If I have understood your code correctly, you check if the given value is in the text (strings that need cencorship), and then censor it if it is. Im not sure if that will work with what I am trying to achieve. But in the second guard, it looks like you compare val to all values in dict and then return the key if we find a match, which is what I am  trying to do. It's just accessing the last tuple in the dict I have trouble with.

Comment: @Mampenda Why are you storing the words that need to be censored at the end of the dict? For one, accessing the end of a list take time linear in the length of the list. For another, it gives a certain element of the list a very different semantics from the rest; the fst of the last tuple isn't even used! If you're being given such a list, I recommend parsing it into `data Dictionary = Dictionary { toCensor :: [String], dict :: [(String, [String])] }` first, or similar.